# the divs are going out of bounds and footer is not at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

My issue is that my footer is not sticking to the end of the page and the divs(content of the page) are not in between the footer and nav. Originally I thought it was my footer so I added `height: 2.5rem` to the footer.

But that didn't work on my 1920x1080 screen everything looks fine but when I used inspect in the chrome browser, and change the width of the page, the top most div in the section selector, is either behind my navbar or you only see the bottom half of the div. As for the footer, its in between or on top of the divs that are closest to the end of the page. The footer is at a fixed location that is "considered bottom of my screen" (*NOT* bottom: 0px or below all other contents of the page) and does not move from that spot.

After I decided to change the display in the `.membersSection{} class` and see if will affect anything and I changed `display: grid` to `display: inline-block;` and it put the divs all under the navbar now but the footer is still fixed at the location mentioned above.

In the snippet, if you put it on full page, you are unable to see what I see, but if you just run the snippet you can see what the bug/error that I am seeing in the hosting server that I using for this webpage.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help in fixing this problem towards the right solution would be great!

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.headerNav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 100;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.homePG{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.headerLogin{
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 5px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.navIcon {
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: blue;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}


#mobile-navLinks {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}

#mobile-navLinks form{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 200px;    
}

.headerFormLogin a{
    width: 300px;    
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2.5rem; 
}


.membersSection {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 91.8%;
    padding: 10% 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.memberProfile{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.member{
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.memberImg{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfiloImg {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.memberInfo{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #mobile-navLinks {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    

    .headerLogin{
        display: none;
    }

    .navIcon{
        display: block;
    }
    
        .memberProfile{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    
    .portfiloImg {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .memberInfo h1{
        font-size: 12px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="headerNav">
    <nav>
      <a href="/index.html" class="homePG">HOME</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="headerLogin">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navIcon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mobileNavs()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <div id="mobile-navLinks">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="membersSection">
      <div class="memberProfile">
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername1</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername2</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername3</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername4</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    © 2020 
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Come on with the wording of this request. At least try to help us with some complete sentences.

Comment: Sorry. I did wrote this at night before I slept after I gave up trying to fix my issue. Updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should avoid using % and rem for heights, as these are relative units based on parent containers or root font size.
For the html,body selector, try replacing the height to min-height: 100vh; That way your page will always take up the full size of the browser window as a minimum.

Then set your footer to a specif height, i.e. height: 200px;

Your .headerNav selector needs to include position:absolute for those top,right,left values to actually work. As the header is the first element on your page, you don't need to absolute position it, it's already at the top. If you want it to be sticky, try using position: sticky; instead.

Update .membersSection to display: flex; or inline-flex; if you want to use the flex attributes. i.e. justify-content, align-content. I think you could get away with removing the display and flex rules from the selector all together, as it's an outer container that's not really doing anything.

Give those few things a go, and let us know if it helps solves your problem.

Comment: Updated the code as you suggested, but now when I use inspect or when I shrink the browser size, the header, content, footer are in the right place and aren't overlapping but instead if moves up and leaves a white space gap below the footer and the body's height is still full page length covering the white space.

Comment: I fixed that issue by changing height: 91.8%; in 
.membersSection selector to  height: 91.8vh; but now the divs are going back to out of bounds again if on mobile devices and footer is not at bottom again when its at a certain screen width length around 400-1000px. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: hey pal, I have added a codepen to help you out. The only real way to always have the footer stuck to the bottom is to use position fixed. If you apply a bottom padding to the body of the page to counter the height of the footer, then it provides a 'reveal' affect for the footer. - https://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/qBZyppd

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you can add this to your css:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 635px) {
    footer{
        position:absolute;
        top: 635px;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.headerNav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 100;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.homePG{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.headerLogin{
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 5px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.navIcon {
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: blue;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}


#mobile-navLinks {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}

#mobile-navLinks form{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 200px;    
}

.headerFormLogin a{
    width: 300px;    
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top:150px;
    height: 2.5rem; 
}


.membersSection {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 91.8%;
    padding: 10% 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.memberProfile{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.member{
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.memberImg{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfiloImg {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.memberInfo{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #mobile-navLinks {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    

    .headerLogin{
        display: none;
    }

    .navIcon{
        display: block;
    }
    
        .memberProfile{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    
    .portfiloImg {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .memberInfo h1{
        font-size: 12px;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-height: 635px) {
    footer{
        position:absolute;
        top: 635px;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="headerNav">
    <nav>
      <a href="/index.html" class="homePG">HOME</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="headerLogin">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navIcon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mobileNavs()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <div id="mobile-navLinks">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="membersSection">
      <div class="memberProfile">
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername1</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername2</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername3</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='member'>
                <div class='memberImg'>
                <img class='portfiloImg' src='profiledefault.jpg' alt='Profile Image'> 
                </div>
                <div class='memberInfo'>
                    <h1>Username: aUsername4</h1>
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    © 2020 
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is in how you are using the `position` property and how the box-model works. `position` effectively turns your page from a 2D canvas into a 3D one. You don't need a third dimension for this layout, so it's screwing things up for you.

Use of `inline-block` or `grid` are also both unnecessary. You have a simple block-level element spanning the entirely of the screen. The box-model will place it below everything else if you get rid of the `position` flotsam all over you page.